# How to detect data attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html table like this

```
<td id="18" data-class-index="0" data-day=2017/11/18>18</td>
<td id="19" data-class-index="0" data-day=2017/11/19>19</td>
<td id="20" data-class-index="0" data-day=2017/11/20>20</td>
```

I have `data-day` like `date=2017/11/18`. I would like to get `id` number

I tried like

```
$("id[data-day='2017/11/20']")
```

But it didn't work well.I know it is basic question, but if someone has some idea,Please let me know.

Comment: you can use $("td[data-day='2017/11/20']").attr('id');

Comment: thanks,If I have variable `date =2017/11/20`, How can I achieve it ? I treid `$("td[data-day="+data+"]").attr('id')`  but some error has occured.

Comment: i have added answer plz check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using string literal and `querySelector()`:

```
let data = "2017/11/18";
let id = document.querySelector(`td[data-day= "${data}"]`).id;
console.log(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var val = $('td').filter(function(index){
        return $(this).data('day') == '2017/11/19';
    }).attr('id');
    console.log(val);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log($('table td[data-day="2017/11/20"]').attr('id'));
console.log('__DEBUG__')
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table>
<td id="18" data-class-index="0" data-day="2017/11/18">18</td>
<td id="19" data-class-index="0" data-day="2017/11/19">19</td>
<td id="20" data-class-index="0" data-day="2017/11/20">20</td>
<table>
```

Comment: Thanks,I would like to use variables,like `date = 2017/11/20` and so on, How can I use such variables?

Answer (score -2):

Use the `.data()` method to access it directly

```
var value = $("#20").data("day");
```

See https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/